# In js, Can I use "1 input onkeyup" function as 2 scripts functions, simultaneously?

Tags: javascript

I am coding below code.

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{        
    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    var selectedLang = document.getElementById('lang').value;

    xmlhttp.open("GET","db_"+selectedLang+".php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <select name="lang" id="lang" size="2" style="width:99px;">
        <option value="co">한국어</option>
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="af">Afrikaans</option>
        <option value="ar">Arabic </option>
    </select>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="FirstName" maxlength="20" onkeyup="showUser(this.value)">
    </form>

    <p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint1"></span></p>
    <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

Above code is my ajax function. And below code is another script function. 
But, after execution, first script function doesn't work, but second script function works well.

I want to do 2 actions, simultaneously.

```
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
    if (str.length==0)
    { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }

    var selectedLang = document.getElementById('lang').value;

    xmlhttp.open("GET","ds_hint_"+selectedLang+".php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

HOw can i overcome this problem??
Please, Help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the onkeyup call another function that in turn calls both functions

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" maxlength="20" onkeyup="showUser(this.value)">


function showUser(str){
 showUserFunctionOne(str);
 showUserFunctionTwo(str);
}

function showUserFunctionOne(str)
  {
  if (str.length==0)
  { 
   document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML="";
   return;
  }
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  }

 var selectedLang = document.getElementById('lang').value;

 xmlhttp.open("GET","ds_hint_"+selectedLang+".php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }

function showUserFunctionTwo(str)
    {

   if (str=="")
   {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
  }
 var selectedLang = document.getElementById('lang').value;

 xmlhttp.open("GET","db_"+selectedLang+".php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```